# Handling of mySQL sub-query returning multiple rows

Tags: mysql

Here is my example:

```
select row_x from table_1 where row_y = (select row_a from table_2 where row_b = x)
```

The problem that I am running into is that my query needs to return multiple rows if the subquery returns multiple rows.

Ideally it would translate to something similar to:

```
 'select row_x from table_1 where row_y = '<first row from subquery>' or row_y = '<second row from subquery>' etc.
```

How can I make this happen? Thanks!

Comment: What if you do `row_y IN (subquery)`?

Answer (score 16):

You are looking for IN clause

```
select row_x from table_1 
 where row_y 
 IN (
     select row_a from table_2 where row_b = x
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT t1.row_x FROM table_1 t1 JOIN table_2 t2 ON t1.row_y=t2.row_a WHERE t2.row_b = x
```

Comment: I believe this would be more efficient anyway.